# Why does a wave of single frequency travelling through the waveguide has group velocity?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, velocity, microwaves, waveguide

Suppose we have a waveguide which is fed with electromagnetic wave having a single frequency of say 4GHz, if we are given the cutoff frequency we can determine the group velocity, but in order to define group velocity we need some range of frequencies. I am unable to understand why does it have a group velocity when a single frequency wave is propagating?

Please help me understand.

Comment: Is this for an experiment that lasts for infinite time, both into the past and into the future? (hint: if it isn't, then it isn't a single frequency.)

Comment: @Emilio Pisanty thank you. I didn't know that signal should exist forever for the signal to have single frequency. I just understood that concept.

Comment: "group velocity" is just the slope of the wavenumber-frequency function, no need to assume any group of anything, it is just a derivative of a differentiable function. If you have a narrow group of frequencies then that slope can also be interpreted as the velocity of the envelope but that is an *interpretation* of a slope of a function.